# tastypie - Remove m2m inside another m2m

Tags: django, tastypie

I have 2 resources with foreign keys to each other, like:

```
class GroupResource(ModelResource):
    categories = fields.ToManyField(CategoryResource, 'category_set', 'categories', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Group.objects.all()


class CategoryResource(ModelResource):
    subcategories = fields.ToManyField(SubcategoryResource, 'subcategory_set', 'subcategories', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Category.objects.all()
```

When I list the `GroupResource` it also list the `subcategories`. How can I prevent that and just list the `categories` and not the `subcategories`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `use_in='list'` to the subcategories in `Category`

```
class CategoryResource(ModelResource):
  subcategories = fields.ToManyField(SubcategoryResource, 'subcategory_set', 'subcategories', full=True, use_in='list')

  class Meta:
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of detail you'd like included when listing you can try setting `full_list=False` on the categories relationship or using `full_list` and `full_detail` on the subcategories to alter the output.

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.full_list

Comment: Thx man. It almost worked. In the end, I added the `use_in='list'` to the `Subcategory`.